# At last time skype isnt started?

Tags: skype

Very much pleasant to me your production. But recently it is not started Skype and after reinstallation Ubuntu has changed nothing. I ask to help or prompt the decision

Sorry if the text is written incorrectly, Im russian)

ubuntu 11.10

Ukraine,Kiev

Answer (score 1):

Try at a terminal

```
sudo apt-get purge skype
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install skype
```

Skype is known to not run after an upgrade to 11.10, the new package is a different version.